# how to use pulseaudio to detect name of media player?

Tags: pulseaudio, pavucontrol

I am new to the pulse audio system.I want design application which required show name of  media player which currently playing audio or video like play tab shows in the pavucontrol (pulseaudio volume control). I read the pulse audio API documentation on Doxygen
( http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/index.html) 
but I don't get it . please help me....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I wouldn't use Pulseaudio's API directly for this. Pulseaudio exposes a [DBus interface](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/DBus/) which you can use for this. This is not a full answer so posting just a comment. Does using DBus also qualify for what you're trying to achieve? (tip: use `qdbusviewer` to find the appropriate keys)

Comment: thanx, for suggestion but  i am using pulse audio. using sink_input_infolist function in API I am getting full information which i need for my project.